# Prove there are 3 points on the circle having same colour

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> All the points of a circle are randomly coloured red or blue. Prove there
>   are 3 points on the circle having same colour, representing an
>   isosceles triangle.

Comment: How many points are there in a circle?

Comment: @hdl all the points are coloured.

Comment: yes, but _how many_ are there? :o)

Comment: @hdl many many many many ...

Comment: You're right, infinitely many, and now how many colours do you have to colour your infinite amount of points?

Comment: You really should make a different question for the update. Though I think the answer to the update is much easier than for the original.

Comment: @hdl You seem to have read only the title, rather than the question.

Comment: This is http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/even_spaced.shtml.

Comment: "All the points of a circle..." This statement is ambiguous. It could refer to all points on the circumference or all points included in the circle's area.

Comment: @jpmc26 No, it's not ambiguous. What you refer to as "the circle's area" is a _disk_, not a _circle_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Given the number of times I've heard reference to, "the area of a circle," as opposed to, "the area of a disk," even in mathematical contexts, I would contend that definition is restricted to a narrow, strict, formal, high level (perhaps even "niche" might apply) usage, and that it's inappropriate to expect that level of strict terminology to apply to a public forum where users have a vastly varying level of knowledge and experience. There is no downside to being explicit that the circumference is intended.

Comment: @jpmc26 You may have a point. Being more explicit would not be bad. On the other hand there is that other universe where circle and disk mean clearly different things - when I talk to my (grad) students about one they don't think I mean the other. So calling the OP "ambiguous" really seems a little strong.

Comment: @jpmc26 Actually "the circumference" is not intended, because the circumference is only a measure of a circle, equals $2 \pi R$.Also, using a precise language is what mathematics is all about. No one has to make concessions for the sake of audience.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Incorrect. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/circumference It can also mean the boundary itself. (I thought of "boundary" later, but it was too late to edit.) "No one has to make concessions for the sake of audience." This denies the very nature of language itself; language is a set of conventions understood by both speaker/writer and listener/reader. If your reader is not a member of the group that has these conventions you expect, then you must accommodate in order for them to be able to understand, either by clarifying your conventions or choosing different terms.

Comment: @jpmc26 Let's drop it. You didn't get my point.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take regular pentagon. The three points are the same color.

[image]

Comment: An excellent solution.

Comment: Right on the spot.

Comment: I was wondering what tool you used to generate the image so quickly :)

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I think I recognise GeoGebra

Comment: @tomsmeding - thanks :) Didn't know this existed, this is great

Comment: Not so much a hint as an almost complete answer...

Answer (score 4):

In the wonderfully clever solution given, starting with that pentagon, the two possible monochromatic triangles are not congruent. It may be interesting to note that this is of necessity.

Say an $\alpha$-triangle is an isoceles triangle in which the two sides of equal length meet at an angle $\alpha$.

Fix an angle $\alpha$. There exists a coloring of the points of the cirle with two colors, such that no $\alpha$-triangle is monochromatic.

Say the circle is the unit circle $S$ in the complex plane. Given $\alpha$, there exists a complex number $\beta$ with $|\beta|=1$ such that the vertices of any $\alpha$-triangle are $z,\beta z,\beta^2z$ for some $z$. For $z\in S$ define $$C_z=\{\beta^nz:n\in\Bbb Z\}.$$Then the $C_z$ form a partition of $S$; choose a coloring so that $\beta^nz$ and $\beta^{n+1}z$ always have different colors.

**Oops** Unless the sequence $\beta^n z$ is periodic with period $k$, for $k$ odd. In that case color $z,\dots,\beta^{k-1}z$ with alternating colors. (So now $\beta^{k-1}z$ and $\beta^{k}z$ have the same color, but it doesn't matter, there are no three consecutive $n$ for which $\beta^nz$ all have the same color.) Thanks to stewbasic for noticing the gap.

Comment: I think you mean n in Z. Also if beta is a root of unity with odd degree, then you can't ensure C_z has no two consecutive points the same color (but you could for three consecutive points).

Comment: @stewbasic Thanks. Typo. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

Not anywhere near as elegant as the five-equidistant-point proof, but I've a nine-point brute-force proof.

Premise: any point on a circle will form an icoseles triangle with points placed equidistantly either side.

Pick any number of points separated by distance X.

If any three sequential points are red (111) or blue (000) then there's an isosceles triangle between those three points, of length 2X. So we need a sequence with no more than two of each color, ever.

But by the same logic, any sequence that repeats with period P, will have an isoceles triangle by the beginning of the third repeat, of length 2PX.

Which means no short sequence can possibly be made which, when repeated, prevents the triangle.

So if we find the longest binary number made of alternating (1 or 11) and (0 or 00) where no element appears three times separated by the same interval, and we find it's infinitely long, then we've got a winner. This seems unlikely.

We'll start with all 8 possible combinations of "1, (0 or 00), (1 or 11), (0 or 00), 1", and add more to each until they repeat, or it becomes obvious that they will not.

```
1 10101 - repeat, 1x1x1.

2 101001 -
    10100101 -
      101001010 - repeat, xxxx0x0x0.
      101001011 - repeat, xx1xx1xx1.
    10100100 - repeat, x0xx0xx0.
    10100110 - repeat, x0xx0xx0.

3 1011001 -> repeat, 1xx1xx1

4 101101 - 
    10110101 - repeat, xxx1x1x1
    10110100 - repeat, x0xx0xx0

5 100101 - mirror of 101001.

6 1001001 - repeat, 1xx1xx1.

7 1001101 - mirror of 1011001: repeat, 1xx1xx1.

8 10011001 -
    100110010 - repeat, xx0xx0xx0
    100110011 - repeat, 1xxx1xxx1
```

There is no binary number longer than 9 digits in which neither 1 or 0 appears twice at a set interval. Which means that picking nine equidistant points around the circle is sufficient to prove the principle.